# How do I construct and use an object inside the inner class of a nested class?

Tags: java, audio, nested-class

I posted this earlier, but it wasn't quite up to par with stackoverflow standards. I cleaned up the code and articulated my question a bit more, so here goes:

I'm making a two player asteroids game in an applet for a CS1 project. I'm trying to figure out how to implement sound effects using methods I can call at certain times. I found this tutorial (http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/14083-incredibly-easy-way-to-play-sounds/) on doing just that, but I'm having some trouble with the nested loop syntax.

How do I construct the 'Sound' object within the Sound class from a different class (in my case, AsteroidsGame.java) ?

Because of the messiness of the tutorial code, here's mine for improved readability.

```
//Import Statements
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Audioapp extends JApplet
{
public class Sound // Holds one audio file
{
    private AudioClip song; // Sound player
    private URL songPath;   // Sound path

    Sound(String filename)
    {
        try
        {
            songPath = new URL(getCodeBase(),filename); // Get the Sound URL
            song = Applet.newAudioClip(songPath); // Load the Sound
        }
        catch(Exception e){} // Satisfy the catch
    }

  //Loops audio file
  public void playSound()
  {
     song.loop();
  }


  //Stops audio file
  public void stopSound()
  {
     song.stop();
  }


  //Plays audio file once
  public void playSoundOnce()
  {
     song.play();
  }

} //Closes Sound()


  public void init()
  {
    Sound testsong = new Sound("song.mid");
    testsong.playSound();
  }

} //Closes Audioapp()
```

Edit 1: Just remembered someone from the last thread suggested I post what this does when I compile/run it. This .java on it's own does nothing; but it does indeed compile without errors when placed with the rest of my project.

Edit 2: Thanks a lot Zim-Zam for all your help, if anyone finds this thread and has the same issue, please consult his comments.

Comment: FYI `catch(Exception e){}` is never a good idea.

Comment: *"an applet for a CS1 project"*  See [Why should CS teachers stop teaching applets?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196499/why-should-cs-teachers-stop-teaching-applets)

Comment: *"..someone from the last thread.."*  On that matter, please in future edit your question rather than delete it and start a new one.  People who offer advice typically do not like to have to repeat themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you change your inner class to `public static class Sound` - this will let you construct instances of the class without needing an instance of `Audioapp`.

Then, to create an instance of `Sound`, you simply treat it as though its name were `Audioapp.Sound`, e.g. `Audioapp.Sound sound = new Audioapp.Sound()`

If the inner class isn't static, then you would use `Audioapp.Sound sound = audioApp.new Sound()`, where `audioapp` is an instance of `Audioapp`

Comment: The first recommendation nearly worked, but I'm getting a "non-static method getCodeBase() cannot be referred to from a static context" error. Any ideas?

Comment: A static inner class can only reference static methods and fields in the enclosing class - you'll either need to change the method to static, or change the class back to non-static

Comment: I changed my Sound class back to non-static, and then went with your second recommendation. I however am receiving a "cannot find symbol" and it's pointing to audioapp, which in your OP was an instance of Audioapp.

Comment: You'll either need to instantiate an instance of `Audioapp` called `audioapp` before you reference the symbol, or else you can change it to a throwaway instance with `Audioapp.Sound sound = (new Audioapp()).new Sound()`

Comment: That worked great, Thanks! One more quick question if you wouldn't mind. How would I reference what we just created, and use the playSound() method to play that audio file? I know the usual syntax is object.Method(), but when I attempt to use sound.playSound() it expects an identifier. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You reference the inner class's methods/fields the same as any other class's, with `object.method()` or `object.field`; be sure that your `sound` object isn't out of scope when you try to reference it.  If you declare the object in a method or within a block `{ .. }`, then you can't use the object outside of the method/block (unless you assign the object to a variable with greater scope, e.g. `Audioapp.Sound sound1 = null; {Audioapp.Sound sound2 = (new AudioApp()).new Sound(); sound1 = soun2;}` will let you reference `sound1` (but not `sound2`) outside of the block